# ReactNative ScrollView will not scroll to the bottom

Tags: react-native, scrollview

If I try to scroll to the bottom of my ScrollView, it bounces back to its default position and won't let me view the entirety of its content.

My ( truncated ) setup is fairly simple :

```js
  <View>
    <View>
      <ABunchOfStuff />
    </View>   
    <View style={styles.sectionNode} >
      <ABunchOfStuff />
    </View>   
    <ScrollView>    <------ My broken ScrollView :(
      <View>
        <ABunchOfStuff />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>   
  </View>
```

This is a simplified version of my actual code. But I'm reaching the conclusion that there's some kind of "unbounded height" going on [as in this reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html).

I did try making sure everything and all parents have `flex: 1` all the way to the child `<View>` of my `<ScrollView>` and up to its parents. But that didn't seem to do the trick.

Any idea on how to debug this? I know ReactNative's website recommends this and says it would be easy to do in the inspector ( but with no instructions on how to do it ). If my assumption that there's an "unbounded height" issue, how would one go about and find this rascal unbounded node? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bounded height thingy means the `ScrollView` itself must be bound.
If the ScrollView has unbounded height, it will stretch with your content and won't scroll.

You can just add `height` to the `ScrollView` and see how this works, from there on you can use absolute height or use flex in a way that will limit the `ScrollView` height to what you want.

Comment: Hmm.. even if I explicitly set a high to the ScrollView, it still bounces back.

Comment: What do you mean by "bounces back"? Does is randomly go from the middle to the start? What happens and when?

Comment: Adding: 
height: "90%" fixed my issues, the percent will vary depending on your container

Answer (score 44):

Try taking flex out of the `ScrollView` entirely and just put `flex: 1` on the parent. That did the trick for me.

Comment: You are a saviour. It worked for me too but i have to put `flex:1` to all parents of `ScrollView`.

Comment: Worked. Also, if you want to add padding, add a direct child `View` and add the padding to that.

Answer (score 19):

For me the problem was setting a `paddingVertical`, `paddingTop` or `paddingBottom` on the ScrollView. Just don't do that. it influences the height of the content of the ScrollView, without the ScrollView adjusting to it appropriately.

Comment: Add the padding to a child `View`

Answer (score 11):

The parent view must have style={{flex: 1}} then the scrollview can have style={{flex: 1}}

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
   <ScrollView>
      <View style={{paddingTop: 16, paddingBottom: 16}}>
         <SearchBar />
         <ItemsContainer />
      </View>
   </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: Also check if the children (SearchBar and ItemsContainer) have any height restriction bothering. I had to remove those restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

You must make sure that `ScrollView` has fixed height, either by setting it for parents or for itself.

I use flex to set its height instead of specifying it directly so it works on all screen size. So for your code something like

```js
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View>
      <ABunchOfStuff />
    </View>   
    <View style={styles.sectionNode} >
      <ABunchOfStuff />
    </View>   
    <ScrollView style={{flex:0.8}}>
      <View>
        <ABunchOfStuff />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>   
</View>
```

More information in react native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)

Comment: I do have flex set for every node up and down the chain. And also linked the same link you included in my question.

Comment: Can you update question with the style elements for each view? I had similar problem, and I looked at my code again. I have ScrollView wrapped in a View, which has a flex instead of setting it itself in ScrollView. Can you check the updated answer?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
    <ScrollView>
       <View style={{height:2000}}>

       </View>
    <ScrollView>
```

The important thing is to put a defined height for the elements that are inside the ScrollView

Answer (score 2):

The suggested answers above with parent  flex: 1 and child  flex: 1 work, but this thing was causing my bug.
I had `<Image> with percentage height` and once I **replaced the percentage with a number**, it fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I had my image and it's container View height set using percentage, I changed it to number and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView  style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: 30}} /> 
    items
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to wrap the ScrollView in View. Then giving the View a height and setting flex : 1 on ScrollView.

Something like this:

```
 <View style={{ height: "60%" }}>
     <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <List/>
     </ScrollView>
 </View>
```

Answer (score -1):

add `<Text></Text>`
at the bottom inside scrollview. it will give some space

Answer (score -1):

this will solve your problem

```html
    <ScrollView
     contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1,justifyContent:'space- 
      between'}}
      >
       <The Other Components or Lists/>
     </ScrollView>
```